# $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme from $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, terminology, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$, and let $J=I\cap\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]$.

Consider $X=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]/I)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[T_1,\dotsc,T_n]/J)$.

Then $Y\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})=X$.

In this way an affine $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme $X$ gives rise to an affine $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme $Y$ such that $Y\times_{\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})}\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{Q})=X$.

I am wondering if this construction of $Y$ from $X$ has a name in scheme theory.

(I am an absolute beginner)

Comment: This is usually called a descent of $X$.

Comment: @CaptainLama: Thank you. I'm googling and I see information of descent theory and descent datum. Still trying to figure out the precise relationship between and the various results on google. If you could add a few more words that would be helpful and much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is *not* a well-defined construction on a $\mathbb Q$-scheme $X$. That is, the construction depends on the presentation of the scheme. For example, $\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Q[x]/x$ and $\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Q[x]/(2x-1)$ are clearly isomorphic, but the construction gives $\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z[x]/x\cong\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z[x]/(2x-1)\cong\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z_{(2)}$, respectively, which are *not* isomorphic.

However, such problems are important in scheme theory, namely: given a morphism $S'\to S$ and a scheme $X'$ over $S'$, when does $X'$ arise as a fiber product $X\times_SS'$ for a scheme $X\to S$, and if so, can you explicitly construct such a scheme $X$?

Examples are when $S'=\mathrm{Spec}(L)$ and $S=\mathrm{Spec}(K)$, where $L/K$ is a Galois extension. Then the problem is usually known as *Galois descent*, and is analogous to the theory of Galois descent for vector spaces.

When $S'=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ and $S=\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/x^2)$ (or perhaps the formal scheme $\mathrm{Spf} k[[x]]$) for some field $k$, then the problem is usually called *deformation theory*.

In your particular example, we have $S'=\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Q$ and $S=\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z$. You give one construction for affine schemes over $S'$, but I believe extending the construction to arbitrary $\mathbb Q$-schemes is still not easy, since it is unclear how the construction on the affine patches glue together (precisely because the construction is on the level of presentations, not on the level of rings). Here, I believe the key word is *integral models*.

---

Here is a geometric interpretation of OP's construction. Let $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}^n$ be a closed subscheme. There is a morphism $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}^n\subset\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^n$. The composition is a morphism $X\to\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^n$, and the scheme-theoretic image is your $Y$ (see the [Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01R6).)

This construction generalizes: Let $Z\hookrightarrow X$ be a closed immersion of $\mathbb Q$-schemes. If $X=X'\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z}\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Q$ for some $\mathbb Z$-scheme $X'$, then $Z'$, the scheme-theoretic image of $Z\hookrightarrow X\to X'$ is such that $Z=Z'\times_{\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Z}\mathrm{Spec}\ \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful. I'm thinking about this. Regarding your first paragraph: So my construction is not well defined for an affine $\mathbb{Q}$-scheme $X$. But I think it is well defined if we take the morphism $X\to\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^n$ as part of the structure of the input. So maybe my construction can be described scheme theoretically for affine $\mathbb{Q}$-schemes with this extra strucutre? Or do we need to require some extra properties from the morphism $X\to\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^n$? I'm happy to focus on affine schemes for now.

Comment: You at least want your morphism $X\to\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}^n$ to be a closed immersion, since otherwise, when $n=0$ there is no extra data. But then I believe you are correct, since a closed immersion $X\hookrightarrow\mathbb A_{\mathbb Q}^n$ is the same data as a presentation.

Comment: OK, great. So now I'm wondering, given a closed immersion $X\to\mathbb{Q}_{\mathbb{Q}}^n$, is there a construction of my $Y$ in geometric terms? Is it the limit of some diagram or something like that?

Comment: (should have been $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{Q}^n$ of course.)

Comment: In terms of rings, the input is a quotient map $\mathbb{Q}[T_1,...,T_n]\to\mathbb{Q}[T_1,...,T_n]/I$, giving rise to a map $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,...,T_n]\to\mathbb{Q}[T_1,...,T_n]/I$, and $Y$ is the spectrum of the image of the latter map. So I'm wondering if this can be said in geometric terms without going to the ring world.

Comment: I have addressed your question in a new edit.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @KReiser Sorry, you are right! I'll fix the post. Thankfully, this does not matter for the rest of the post.

Comment: No worries, and it indeed doesn't affect the rest of the post. I've removed my previous comment, have a good day!